# Like and Unlike Counter works on first post but not on second

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My like and unlike counter works for the first post but it won't work for my second post.

sweettune.info/hashtest/red/index.php

The like and unlike counter works perfectly in localhost but when I upload it to GoDaddy it doesn't work.

I am using `mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);`. But when I change it to `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` I get a page not working error.

```
<div class="posts-wrapper">
   <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <div class="post">
      <?php echo $post['text']; ?>
      <div class="post-info">
        <!-- if user likes post, style button differently -->
        <i <?php if (userLiked($post['id'])): ?>
              class="fa fa-thumbs-up like-btn"
          <?php else: ?>
              class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like-btn"
          <?php endif ?>
          data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>"></i>
        <span class="likes"><?php echo getLikes($post['id']); ?></span>

        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <!-- if user dislikes post, style button differently -->
        <i 
          <?php if (userDisliked($post['id'])): ?>
              class="fa fa-thumbs-down dislike-btn"
          <?php else: ?>
              class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down dislike-btn"
          <?php endif ?>
          data-id="<?php echo $post['id'] ?>"></i>
        <span class="dislikes"><?php echo getDislikes($post['id']); ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
   <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Define "not working"?

Comment: what kind of error did you get it? can you show the implementation of  getLikes function

Comment: @Quirel Heres how it works sweettune.info/hashtest/red/index.php

Comment: @S0HS Heres how it works: sweettune.info/hashtest/red/index.php

Comment: Im'm getting a blank page. so nothing happens

Comment: You didn't show us the mysqli code.

Comment: Check the PHP error log to see the reason for the "page not working" error.

Comment: You probably mistyped something, because `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is exactly equivalent to calling `mysqli_fetch_array` with the `MYSQLI_ASSOC` flag.